# Etiquette of error codes in COM

Tags: com

In a COM object generally there are two ways of indicating that a function failed (that I'm aware of):

- return `S_OK` and have an `[out]` parameter to give failure info
- return a failure `HRESULT`, and use `ICreateErrorInfo` to set the info.

Currently what I am doing is using the failure-`HRESULT` method for failures that are "really bad", i.e. my object will be basically inoperable because this function failed. For example, unable to open its configuration file.

Is this correct, or should failure HRESULTs be reserved only for things like dispatch argument type mismatches?

Comment: The lowest level COM standard is to return HRESULT w/o out parameter and w/o ICreateErrorInfo. ICreateErrorInfo is more related to Automation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221375(v=vs.85).aspx so it really depends what your client/caller is or will be

Comment: I have lots of clients and want to support them all properly . For example one client is VB6, and if I return a non-ok HRESULT without setting ErrorInfo, it pops up a display "Method '~' of '~' failed", which is not very useful - however if I do set ErrorInfo then it displays that info instead.

Comment: VB6 is an Automation client, so yes, it's better to use your 2nd option. If you google 'ICreateErrorInfo .net', you should find Andrew Troelsen's 'COM and .NET Interoperability' book pages 456 & 460 that details this a bit.

Comment: COM is big. All COM books are old books IMHO :) I've used: "Professional DCOM Programming" (not only for DCOM...), "Essential COM", "Professional ATL COM programming", "ATL internals" (ATL is a must with C++, but these ATL books may be quite outdated since ATL has evolved), and ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" for COM with NET.

Comment: Don't forget that `ICreateErrorInfo` works together with `ISupportErrorInfo`, not on its own. MSDN describes it here: [Automation Reference - Returning Error Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221062). for higher level cliens it's preferable ways to pass extended error information. For lower level APIs it's not widely used, and it's pretty expensive to implement support for ErrorInfo in full.

Comment: You say you only use a failure HRESULT for catastrophic failures. You should use them for most forms of failure, not just critical ones.

Comment: @EuroMicelli OK, that's really what my question is about ... can you give any more guidelines or examples?  Part of my concern stems from seeing that VB clients throw an exception whenever a failure HRESULT occurs, so it makes it annoying for them to handle a routine operation that occasionally fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version:

In COM you should use `HRESULT`s (and strive to use `ISupportErrorInfo`, etc.) for most/all types of error conditions. The `HRESULT` mechanism should be viewed as a form of exception throwing. If you are familiar with that, consider "Error conditions" as anything for which you would normally throw an exception in a language that supports them. Use custom return values for things for which you would not normally use exceptions.

For example, use a failure HRESULT for invalid parameters, invalid sequence of operations, network failures, database errors, unexpected conditions such as out-of-memory, etc. On the other hand, use custom out parameters for things like 'polling, data is not ready yet', EOF conditions, maybe 'checked data and it doesn't pass validations'. There is plenty of discussions out there discussing what each should be (e.g. Stroustrup's [TC++PL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840)). The specifics will heavily depend on your particular object's semantics.

The longer version:

At a fundamental level, the COM HRESULT mechanism is just an error code mechanism which has been standardized by the infrastructure. This is mostly because COM must support a number of features such as inter-process (DCOM) and inter-threaded (Apartments) execution, system managed services (COM+), etc. The infrastructure has a need to know *when* something has failed, and it has a need to communicate to both sides its own infrastructure-related errors. Everybody needs to agree on how to communicate errors.

Each language and programmer has a choice of how to present or handle those errors. In C++, we typically handle the HRESULTs as error codes (although you can translate them into exceptions if you prefer error handling that way). In .NET languages, failure HRESULTs are translated into exceptions because that's the preferred error mechanism in .NET.

VB6 supports "either". Now, I know VB6's so-called exception handling has a painful syntax and limited scoping options for handlers, but you don't have to use it if you don't want to. You can always use `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` and do it by hand if you think the usage pattern justifies it in a specific situation. It's just that instead of writing something like this:

```
statusCode = obj.DoSomething(param1)
If IS_FAILURE(statusCode) Then
    'handle error
End If
```

Your write it like this:

```
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
...
obj.DoSomething param1
IF Error.Number <> 0 Then
    'handle error
End If
```

VB6 is simply hiding the error code return value from the method call (and allowing the object's programmer to substitute it for a "virtual return value" via `[retval]`).

If you make up your own error reporting mechanism instead of using `HRESULT`s, you will:

1. Spend a lot of time reinventing a rich error reporting mechanism that will probably mirror what ISupportsErrorInfo already gives you (or most likely, not provide any rich error information).
2. Hide the error status from COM's infrastructure (which might or might not matter).
3. Force your VB6 clients to make one specific choice out of the two options they have: they must do explicit line-by-line check, or more likely just ignore the error condition by mistake, even if they would prefer an error handler.
4. Force your (say) C# clients to handle your errors in ways that runs contrary to the natural style of the language (to have to check every method call explicitly and... likely throw an exception by hand).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great writeup and just what I was looking for.